# NextJs: Element is not Defined when using Intro.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

Why did I get the following error while using `intro.js` in next my project?

```
ReferenceError: Element is not defined <br/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because **intro.js** uses the DOM API and on the SSR your document object model is not available.

You need to dynamically import intro.js into your project and disable ssr for it. Something like this should solve your problem:

```
// component with your intro.js logic

const Steps = dynamic(() => import('intro.js-react').then(mod => mod.Steps), {
  ssr: false
});
const Hints = dynamic(() => import('intro.js-react').then(mod => mod.Hints), {
  ssr: false
});
```

Comment: Tried but did not work for me...

```javascript
Argument of type '() => Promise<ComponentClass<never, any> | FunctionComponent<never> | { default: ComponentType<never>; } | typeof Steps>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DynamicOptions<{}> | Loader<{}>'.
```

Comment: By ignoring the above with `// @ts-ignore`, it worked but typescript error remained.