# ReferenceError: Element is not defined (Object.<anonymous>) in Intro.js-react, React, Next.js and Tailwind CSS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, intro.js

Code is like here.

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Steps } from 'intro.js-react';

export default function Dashboard() {

  const [stepEnabled, setStepEnabled] = useState(true);
  const steps = [
    {
      intro: 'Welcome to WorkStats!'
    }
  ];
  const onExit = () => {
    setStepEnabled(false);
  };

  return (
    <main>
      <Steps
        enabled={stepEnabled}
        steps={steps}
        initialStep={0}
        onExit={onExit}
      />
      <div>Test</div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

An error is like this.

[image: Error screen]

This error is similar to this issue [NextJs: Element is not Defined when using Intro.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71687633/nextjs-element-is-not-defined-when-using-intro-js/72657092#72657092) but it did not work for me.

As you can see in the attached screenshot, the error is saying that it is because an element is not defined in the `Object.<anonymous>`.

This `Object.<anonymous>` is `<Steps>`. Comment this out, because if you comment it out, the error goes away. And `<Steps>` is imported from intro.js-react. And intro.js-react is indeed already installed, as shown in the attached third screenshot below.

[image]

Let's look a little more inside the node_module as mentioned in the error message. In the attached third screenshot, if you look at line 310, character 110, you will see that there is indeed an `Element`. According to the attached first error message, this is not defined. I do not know why this is.

[image]

The `step.element` in this `<Steps>` is not `isRequired`. I don't understand why they say that `Element is not defined`.

By the way, I get this error when I reload, but once I comment it out and reload it again, it displays correctly. If I uncomment out the commented out section again after this, the intro.js-react pops up correctly. I think this is another hint, but I don't know why.

Comment: `const Steps = dynamic(` Add this statement after your imports, not inside the component

Comment: Thanks, @Inder but nothing special changed for me.
Updated code as you advised just in case.

Comment: It is working for me. https://postimg.cc/9zZMYqk2

Comment: Have you imported the css file for introjs?

Comment: Thank you @Inder, yes I have imported the CSS file in another file, _app.tsx, which is used  in all pages.

Comment: The original error is already resolved, but this error is still there. 
> As a minor but important detail, I only defined three steps, but there were four... What the heck is the second pop-up, there is one mysterious step.

Answer (score 1):

I updated the next day.
Modified code as below, which resolved the original error.

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
// import { Steps } from 'intro.js-react';

// Newly added
// @ts-ignore
const Steps = dynamic(() => import('intro.js-react').then((mod) => mod.Steps), {
  ssr: false
});

export default function Dashboard() {

  const [stepEnabled, setStepEnabled] = useState(true);
  const steps = [
    {
      intro: 'Welcome to WorkStats!'
    }
  ];
  const onExit = () => {
    setStepEnabled(false);
  };

  return (
    <main>
      <Steps
        // @ts-ignore
        enabled={stepEnabled}
        steps={steps}
        initialStep={0}
        onExit={onExit}
      />
      <div>Test</div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Then the original error "Element is not defined" was gone but the problem still existed. The problem is like this.

https://www.loom.com/share/22a307b2221f42d5b3548647f5da23fc?t=5

The screen darkened for a moment and there was a feeling that a pop-up might appear, but it quickly brightened, and eventually, no pop-up appeared.

If you look at the console log, you see that something appears and disappears for a moment. Here is a screenshot of that moment. It is hard to see, but it still looks like a popup caused by Intro.js-react.

[image]

Here's what it looks like when zoomed in.

[image]

However, if you look at it carefully, you will see that both `top` and `left`, which probably specify the position, are `0px`, and `width` and `height`, which may be the width and height of the popup, are also `0px`. It looks as if nothing will show up on the screen. I don't know why these values are set.

---

After modifying one more part of the code, the popup finally appeared without any errors.

Before

```js
  const onExit = () => {
    setStepEnabled(false);
  };
```

After

```js
  const onExit = () => {
    setStepEnabled(true); // Changed from "false" to "true"
  };
```

However, I am unclear why this worked. Since it is unclear, I was able to avoid the error in front of me, but I cannot apply it in the future. I would like you to continue to tell me why.

https://www.loom.com/share/a88fa3e835a44986889664151f030bfe

As a minor but important detail, I only defined three steps, but there were four... What the heck is the second pop-up, there is one mysterious step.